# Extending Java Enums

Tags: java, enums

I have a question regarding the best design pattern for code reuse when dealing with Java enums. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is being able to define several enums that model static business collections (sets of constants), but I'd also like to share behavior between them, with minimal coding.

This is trivial to achieve with class inheritance from abstract classes but, since Java enums cannot be extended (they can only implement interfaces), this type of work is tedious and involves a lot of error prone copy/paste work (copying the code from enum to enum). Examples of "business logic" that should be shared among all enums includes converting from/to Strings, instance and logical comparison, etc.

My best shot right now is using helper classes in conjunction with business interfaces, but this only goes so far in reducing code complexity (as all enums still have to declare and invoke the helper classes). See example (just to clarify):

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A, B, C;

    // Just about any method fits the description - equals() is a mere example
    public boolean equals(MyEnum that) {
        ObjectUtils.equals(this, that);
    }
}
```

How do StackOverflowers deal with this "language feature"?

Comment: Could try Lombok and `@Delegate`, I've never tried it with an enum.

Comment: In Java 6, enums are a final class; you can not extend them.  I believe java 7 is the same.

Comment: Enums are not made for that: either use classes (or classes with enums) or separate the logic; you could use a factory pattern for a case like this (if the behaviour is different enough from enum to enum).

Comment: @DwB - I do know enums are final (it's mentioned in the question). What I'm asking is a legal Java design pattern that will mitigate the problem of writing too much code to get around that and, thus, keep it DRY.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Lombok looks interesting (similar concept to Spring Roo?) but it introduces yet another tool in the build chain. Current version is 0.10.6 which is a no go for me. Just curious, have you deployed it to production yourself?

Comment: Yep; the bytecode manipulation it does is trivial. I'm more concerned about working-ness than versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the same, or combine the Enums into a super-enum.

With Java 8 this will be easier.  You will be able to define a `default` implementation for interface methods and have the `enum` extend the interface.

Comment: What do you mean with combining the `enum`s into a super-`enum`? Wouldn't that be unsafe as value A and B could be compared even if it made no sense?

Comment: It might be unsafe, it rather depends on the context.

Comment: In the end, all other solutions add more complexity without violating the DRY principle, so this seems to be the solution. Crossing my fingers extension classes come to Java, someday...

Answer (score 3):

You can move the reusable logic to dedicated (non-enum) classes and then have the enums delegate to those classes. Here's an example:

[Side note: the inheritance of `PlusTwo extends PlusOne` is not recommended (b/c PlusTwo is not PlusOne). It here just to illustrate the point of being able to extend an existing logic.]

```
public interface Logic {
  public int calc(int n);
}

public static class PlusOne implements Logic {
  public int calc(int n) { return n + 1; }
}

public static class PlusTwo extends PlusOne {
  @Override
  public int calc(int n) { return super.calc(n) + 1; }
}

public static enum X {
  X1, X2;   
  public Logic logic;

  public int doSomething() { 
    return logic.calc(10);
  }
}

public static enum Y {
  Y1, Y2;
  public Logic logic;

  public String doSomethingElse() { 
    return "Your result is '" + logic.calc(10) + "'";
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  // One time setup of your logic:
  X.X1.logic = new PlusOne();
  X.X2.logic = new PlusTwo();  
  Y.Y1.logic = new PlusOne();
  Y.Y2.logic = new PlusTwo();

  System.out.println(X.X1.doSomething());
  System.out.println(X.X2.doSomething());
  System.out.println(Y.Y1.doSomethingElse());
  System.out.println(Y.Y2.doSomethingElse());
}
```

Comment: In the end, that's just a variation on my initial proposal. It just decouples the implementation logic. I'd also use a factory for `Logic` and not have it exposed like that (as I'm sure you would too, if not for this being just an example).

Answer (score 2):

I rarely find `enums` useful, except for representing finite states in which case they do not need behavior.

I would suggest refactoring `enums` that need behavior into `classes` with a `Factory`.

Comment: enums are a lot safer than using constants to pass around values and lend themselves a lot better to manipulation (EnumSet<...>, `switch`, etc.). I agree they are a lot less powerful than their C# counterpart but they still have their place (especially when you're just refactoring some code and can't do a complete rewrite :) ).

Comment: I agree `enums` are better than the old `final static int CONSTANT = 1` and the syntactic sugar is nice, but every time I have put behavior in an `enum` I have regretted it.

Comment: @Isoliveira Wait **LESS** powerful than the c# enums that are basically syntactic sugar around an int? How did you come to that conclusion? Anyways I agree with Garett to some degree: Enums are there to represent finite states in which case I'm not sure why we'd need to extend them. But having some simple (!) state in enums is often useful imo. If it's more than trivial methods it should be a class though. But e.g. a `getComplement()` method would be fine in my book.

Comment: @Voo - I'd say that is exactly what `enum`s are supposed to be, instead of the neither here nor there syntactic sugar around a final class that's Java's approach. As classes, `enum` tens to be abused to hold all kinds of stuff and, in IMHO, that's a negative thing (I guess what I'm asking could also be perceived as an abuse on `enum`s). Either way, I meant "powerful" as "in this situation the language would allow me to do what I need via extension classes". Given that's another language feature and not something specific to `enum`s, I won't argue with you.

Answer (score 0):

This might look a bit ugly, but generally can offer you the required functionality.

You can have interface

```
public interface MyEnumInterface<T extends Enum<T>> {

    String getBusinessName();

    T getEnum();

}
```

Implementation

```
public enum OneOfMyEnums implements MyEnumInterface<OneOfMyEnums>{

    X, Y, Z;

    @Override
    public String getBusinessName() {
        return "[OneOfMyEnums]" + name();
    }

    @Override
    public OneOfMyEnums getEnum() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

And utility class instead of your parent class

```
public class MyEnumUtils {

    public static <T extends Enum<T>> String doSomething(MyEnumInterface<T> e){
        e.getBusinessName(); // can use MyEnumInterface methods
        e.getEnum().name(); // can use Enum methods as well
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: This approach is interesting but reverses the contract by making the client rely on the utility classes instead of the `enum`s (the `equals()` method goes into `MyEnumUtils`).